# What's the correct way to calculate an average of a variable I am trying to obtain experimentally?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements

I am currently running an experiment with the goal to measure a certain variable $f$. However, I am not able to measure $f$ directly in the given setting. I can however measure another variable $x$ for which I know how it is connected to $f$ (i.e. I know how to calculate $f(x)$).

I am measuring the variable $x$ N-times under the same conditions, in order to improve accuracy.
Should I now first calculate the average $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i$ of my x-values and then plug this into $f(\bar{x})$, or should I calculate $\overline{f(x)}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(x_i)$?

In this particular case $f(\bar{x})\neq \overline{f(x)}$.

Comment: [The second one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Discrete_case).

Answer (score 0):

I don't like $f$, so I'm using $y$. You measure $x_i$ for $i=1, \cdots, N$, leading to $N$ values of $y_i = y(x_i)$.

But you're not ready to calculate $\bar y$ yet; you need to propagate error:

$$ \delta y_i = |\frac{dy}{dx}| \delta x_i$$

where $\delta x_i$ is the uncertainty in the measurement of $x_i$. They may all be equal, different, or unknown. If it's unknown, use the unbiased standard deviation ($\sigma_x$) of the measure $x_i$.

You computed the weight mean:

$$ \bar y = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{y_i}{(\delta y_i)^2}} 
{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac 1 {(\delta y_i)^2}}$$